# SQL SERVER - Summary table, splitting count by row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im new to SQL and Im struggling a bit to analyze some data. I have a table [01-Jan-UserDefined] which is a wind dataset with 20MM lines.
I have created a table [WINDDIR] which generates a summarized table with relevant statistical data, counting data rows by wind speed and wind direction.

The code splits count by column (wind speed) but cant split by the winddirection.

Any tips on how to solve this? Thx

```
UPDATE WINDDIR
SET [0WS1] = counter1,
[1WS2] = counter2,
[2WS3] = counter3,
FROM (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN [01-Jan-UserDefined].[WindRel m s ] <=1 then 1 else null end) AS counter1, 
             COUNT(CASE WHEN [01-Jan-UserDefined].[WindRel m s ] >1 AND [01-Jan-UserDefined].[WindRel m s ] <= 2 then 1 else null end) AS >counter2,
             COUNT(CASE WHEN [01-Jan-UserDefined].[WindRel m s ] >2 AND [01-Jan-UserDefined].[WindRel m s ] <= 3 then 1 else null end) AS counter3,                          
from [01-Jan-UserDefined]) h
```

Data Sample:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @Table AS TABLE ([UTC]               DATETIME
,                        [WindDirRel deg]    INT
,                        [WindRel m s]       DECIMAL(18, 2)
,                        [WINDDIR SECTOR]    NVARCHAR(3)
,                        [WINDDIR SECTOR NO] INT);

INSERT INTO @Table
(   UTC
,   [WindDirRel deg]
,   [WindRel m s]
,   [WINDDIR SECTOR]
,   [WINDDIR SECTOR NO])
VALUES ('27/01/2018 08:09', 127, 3.96, 'ESE', 6)
,      ('27/01/2018 08:09', 125, 4.06, 'ESE', 6)
,      ('27/01/2018 08:09', 125, 4.06, 'ESE', 6)
,      ('13/01/2018 22:01', 13, 10.39, 'N  ', 1)
,      ('13/01/2018 22:01', 12, 10.13, 'N  ', 1)
,      ('13/01/2018 22:01', 12, 10.44, 'N  ', 1);

SELECT * FROM @table
```

Actual output:

```
WINDDIR SECTOR        0WS1 1WS2 2WS3 3W4 4W5 5W6 6W7 7W8 8W9 9W10 10W
N                     0     0    0    1   2   0   0   0   0    0   3
NNE                   0     0    0    1   2   0   0   0   0    0   3      
NE                    0     0    0    1   2   0   0   0   0    0   3
ENE                   0     0    0    1   2   0   0   0   0    0   3
ESE                   0     0    0    1   2   0   0   0   0    0   3
```

Desired output:

```
WINDDIR SECTOR        0WS1 1WS2 2WS3 3W4 4W5 5W6 6W7 7W8 8W9 9W10 10W
N                     0     0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0    0   3
NNE                   0     0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0      
NE                    0     0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0
ENE                   0     0    0    0   0   0   0   0   0    0   0
ESE                   0     0    0    1   2   0   0   0   0    0   0
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your output doesn't make sense. Where do those values comes from? How do you expect to get char values from count?

Comment: Hi Mario.  It looks like your missing a grouping statement of some sort.  I.e. you need to be returning the WINDIR column as part of the sub select. Can I suggest posting some sample data in the format of a TVP and Insert so we can give you a better response?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired reults.

Comment: @Sean, Im not expecting char values, Ive put X, Y and Z to ilustrate different values.

Comment: Hi Mario.  I've updated your data sample so it can be pasted directly into a query. You may want to have a look at it and update your expected results to match.  The easier it is for contributors to work with your data, the more results your likely to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this.  Also note how I've added a sample data set - this will help others help you in future.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (WINDIR NVARCHAR(3), [WindRel m s ] DECIMAL(18, 2));

INSERT INTO @Table (WINDIR, [WindRel m s ])
VALUES (N'N', 0.1)
,      (N'N', 1.5)
,      (N'N', 1.75)
,      (N'N', 2.5)
,      (N'NNE', 1.5)
,      (N'NNE', 2.5);

SELECT WINDIR,COUNT(CASE WHEN [WindRel m s ]<=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [<1]
,COUNT(CASE WHEN [WindRel m s ]>1 AND [WindRel m s ] <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [1-2]
,COUNT(CASE WHEN [WindRel m s ]>2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [>2]
 FROM @Table GROUP BY WINDIR
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your help! 
Thats the idea, but I have to update the result on the WINDDIR table, I don't know if I should place a groupby somewhere or if some kind of join is needed. If it were on powerBI, it would be a missing relationship  link between tables (on the winddir sector column).

Comment: Hi Mario. Easiest way would be to wrap the select in a cte, then join to the windir table and update from there.  I'll post a seperate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (WINDIR NVARCHAR(3), [WindRel m s ] DECIMAL(18, 2));

DECLARE @WINDIR AS TABLE (WINDIR NVARCHAR(3), [0WS1] INT, [1WS2] INT, [2WS3] INT);

INSERT INTO @WINDIR (WINDIR, [0WS1], [1WS2], [2WS3])
VALUES (N'N', 0, 0, 0)
,      (N'NNE', 0, 0, 0);

INSERT INTO @Table (WINDIR, [WindRel m s ])
VALUES (N'N', 0.1)
,      (N'N', 1.5)
,      (N'N', 1.75)
,      (N'N', 2.5)
,      (N'NNE', 1.5)
,      (N'NNE', 2.5);

WITH cte AS
    (SELECT WINDIR
     ,      COUNT(CASE WHEN [WindRel m s ] <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)                         AS [0WS1]
     ,      COUNT(CASE WHEN [WindRel m s ] > 1 AND  [WindRel m s ] <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [1WS2]
     ,      COUNT(CASE WHEN [WindRel m s ] > 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)                          AS [2WS3]
       FROM @Table
      GROUP BY WINDIR)
UPDATE  W
   SET  [0WS1] = cte.[0WS1]
,       [1WS2] = cte.[1WS2]
,       [2WS3] = cte.[2WS3]
  FROM  @WINDIR W
  JOIN  cte ON W.WINDIR = cte.WINDIR;

SELECT  *
  FROM  @WINDIR;
```

Comment: Bravo Matthew! worked perfectly, I'll take a look at the concepts of common table expressions. Thanks again!